# Why some extra tramp related packages does not show url schema prefix?

Tags: tramp

When I press [C-x C-f] , I got some TRAMP methods shown like ssh: , sshx:. But not get docker: when I installed package `docker-tramp`.
Does docker-tramp.el provide this? If yes, then how to configure it? If no, then is it possible to add it?
There are many other tramp related packages like `kubernetes-tramp` and `vagrant-tramp` and `adb:` for Android etc.

Comment: There is no standard `docker-tramp` package.  Please link to the library you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You will see the `docker:` method after loading `docker-tramp`.

Comment: You're right, After `(require 'docker-tramp)`, and disable `ivy-mode` and `counsel-mode`. I can complete `/docker:` in minibuffer now. I guess this is a bug in Ivy. I also tested `ido-mode` and `helm-mode`. Seems happens on them too.